# Custom font faces in jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf

Is it possible to include custom fonts in jsPDF ?

With the basic library, if I console log 'doc.getFontList()' I get:

> Courier, Helvetica, Times, courier, helvetica, times

But, say I want to use 'Comic Sans' ( not that I would ;o) ) can it be done ?

Even better, could I use a font is locally stored and has been declared in the site with @font-face ?

Comment: You can try the detailed question and answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603013/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-jspdf).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found this was possible by modifying `jsPDF.js` to expose the existing `addFont` method in the public API.

In `jsPDF.js`, look for:

```
//---------------------------------------
// Public API
```

Add the following:

```
    API.addFont = function(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle) {
      addFont(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle, 'StandardEncoding');
    };
```

I put this method near other font methods for clarity - `API.setFont`, `API.setFontSize`, `API.setFontType`, etc.

Now in your code, use:

```
doc.addFont('ComicSansMS', 'Comic Sans', 'normal');
doc.setFont('Comic Sans');
doc.text(50,50,'Hello World');
```

This works for me with @font-face fonts included with css before loading jsPDF, as well as system fonts. There's probably a better way to do this using jsPDF's plugin framework, but this quick and dirty solution should at least get you going.

Note that `doc.getFontList()` will **not** show added fonts:

```
// TODO: iterate over fonts array or return copy of fontmap instead in case more are ever added.
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I took your work and issued a PR (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/475), which was just merged into master of jsPDF. Here it is: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js#L1595. Thanks again!

Comment: This one doesn’t work for me with Google Fonts. Nothing is added, no error shown.

Comment: Note however that the font is never embedded in the pdf itself but read from the browser font repository. If you try to save the pdf, the parts using the custom font will be invisible.

Comment: @Integrating Stuff, is PDF generate by javascript cannot embed font to the PDF file?

Comment: jsPDF cant. However, pdfmake - another Javascript library to deal with pdfs - can.

Comment: Is there any way to add FontAwesome to jsPDF so that we can export icons? Also will that possible with bootstrap glyphicons? I think uni codes are not supported by jsPDF.

Comment: Not Working. Please give full example to add font

Answer (score 26):

It seems to be a lot easier with the latest version of [`jsPDF` (1.5.3)](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF):

If you look in the folder `jsPDF-master` > `fontconverter`, there's a file `fontconverter.html`. Open in your browser and use the `Browse...` button to navigate to, and select your `.ttf` font file.

Click 'Create'.

[image]

The page will offer a "download" to be saved. This will produce a `.js` file called [something like] `RopaSans-Regular-normal.js`. This needs to be included in your page producing the PDF's. Personally, I've done it in the main page's header (and please note the order of the `script`s):

```
<!-- pdf creation -->
<script src="FileSaver.js-master/src/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="jsPDF-master/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<!-- custom font definition -->
<script src="path-to-the-file-just-saved/RopaSans-Regular-normal.js" type="module"></script>
```

Now in your PDF generation method in js:

```
doc.setFont('RopaSans-Regular');
doc.setFontType('normal');
```

Comment: Hi man, how could I apply this to my angular´s 7 project? I´d tried to put the script inside angular.json on script´s session, it wasn´t executed. Then I tried to put on index.html, header´s session, again not worked. Can you suggest me another way?

Comment: This is so helpful, saved me from loading TTF file and hanging browser.Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution I'm using...

First, as others have mentioned - you need these two libraries:

1. jsPDF: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
2. jsPDF-CustomFonts-support: https://github.com/sphilee/jsPDF-CustomFonts-support

Next - the second library *requires* that you provide it with at least one custom font in a file named `default_vfs.js`. I'm using *two* custom fonts - Arimo-Regular.ttf and Arimo-Bold.ttf - both from Google Fonts. So, my `default_vfs.js` file looks like this:

(

```
(function (jsPDFAPI) { 
    "use strict";
    jsPDFAPI.addFileToVFS('Arimo-Regular.ttf','[Base64-encoded string of your font]');
    jsPDFAPI.addFileToVFS('Arimo-Bold.ttf','[Base64-encoded string of your font]');
})(jsPDF.API);
```

Obviously, you version would look different, depending on the font(s) you're using.

There's a bunch of ways to get the Base64-encoded string for your font, but I used this: https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/.

It lets you upload a font .ttf file, and it'll give you the Base64 string that you can paste into `default_vfs.js`.

You can see what the actual file looks like, with my fonts, here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/stuehler/jsPDF-CustomFonts-support/master/dist/default_vfs.js

So, once your fonts are stored in that file, your HTML should look like this:

```
    <script src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jspdf.customfonts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/default_vfs.js"></script>
```

Finally, your JavaScript code looks something like this:

```
const doc = new jsPDF({
      unit: 'pt',
      orientation: 'p',
      lineHeight: 1.2
    });

doc.addFont("Arimo-Regular.ttf", "Arimo", "normal");
doc.addFont("Arimo-Bold.ttf", "Arimo", "bold");

doc.setFont("Arimo");
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.setFontSize(28);

doc.text("Hello, World!", 100, 100);

doc.setFontType("bold");

doc.text("Hello, BOLD World!", 100, 150);

doc.save("customFonts.pdf");
```

This is probably obvious to most, but in that `addFont()` method, the three parameters are:

1. The font's name you used in the `addFileToVFS()` function in the `default_vfs.js` file
2. The font's name you use in the `setFont()` function in your JavaScript
3. The font's style you use in the `setFontType()` function in your JavaScript

You can see this working here: https://codepen.io/stuehler/pen/pZMdKo

Hope this works as well for you as it did for me.

Answer (score 5):

After looking at the fontconverter.html, and seeing that it does nothing more than package the TTF files into a base64 string inside a JS file, I came up with the following method that I call before creating my document. It basically does what the individual files resulting from fontconverter.html do, just on-demand:

```
async function loadFont(src, name, style, weight) {
    const fontBytes = await fetch(src).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
    
    var filename = src.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
    var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(fontBytes)));

    var callAddFont = function () {
        this.addFileToVFS(filename, base64String);
        this.addFont(filename, name, style, weight );
        };
    jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont]);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
await loadFont("/css/fonts/exo-2-v9-latin-ext_latin-italic.ttf", "Exo-2", "italic", 400);
await loadFont("/css/fonts/exo-2-v9-latin-ext_latin-regular.ttf", "Exo-2", "normal", 400);
await loadFont("/css/fonts/exo-2-v9-latin-ext_latin-500.ttf", "Exo-2", "normal", 500);
await loadFont("/css/fonts/exo-2-v9-latin-ext_latin-500italic.ttf", "Exo-2", "italic", 500);
```

It loads the font from the URL, and adds it to the VFS and font manager. Important: ***the font name cannot include spaces***. You won't get any warnings, but the resulting PDF will either not open or the text will look funny.

Comment: this was actually the answer i was looking for. I think lots ao folder answers are outdated or half answering it by relying on to much 3rd party  tooling.

Comment: Similar story for me, after looking through all the answers, I came up with the code above to simply load the fonts on-demand. I seriously do not know what the idea with the converter is, as it doesn't really convert anything, just repackage the file, while making it even larger. There is zero reason not to load on demand directly from the TTF file.

Comment: i found out you dont need to go through the event system in (maybe) recent releases of the lib. You can use the calls directly now. Should be easier as well

Comment: @SebastianSchürmann Will check. I wanted to avoid any sort of timing problems that might occur on my development web server, but my pose a problem in the productive environment, so I used the event system.

Comment: Approve word above - Only that solution is currently work. I try get a font from setFontFace but haven't got any result with extraction face from loading via css.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Angular 8 and [Todd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54971101/9164115) worked for me.

Once you get the .js file from fontconverter.html, you can import it in typescript like so:

```
import fontref = require('path/to/font/CustomFont-normal.js')
```

Then all you have to do to load the font is 'call' `fontref`:

```
makePdf() {
    let doc = new jsPDF();

    fontref;                             // 'call' .js to load font

    doc.getFontList();                   // contains a key-value pair for CustomFont

    doc.setFont("CustomFont");           // set font
    doc.setFontType("normal");
    doc.setFontSize(28);
    doc.text("Hello", 20, 20);

    window.open(doc.output('bloburl'));  // open pdf in new tab
  }
```

Comment: Note also you might need to change polyfills.ts to add the import * as jsPDF from "jspdf";(window as any).jsPDF = jsPDF;jsPDF to the window.

Answer (score 2):

Some of these answers are outdated, so I am linking the readme file from Mr. Rio himself regarding the latest release as of this post. Below is a copy of the paragraph from that readme file followed by a link to the readme file itself. Hope this additional resource is helpful:

> **Use of UTF-8 / TTF:**
> The 14 standard fonts in PDF are limited to the
> ASCII-codepage. If you want to use UTF-8 you have to to integrate a
> custom font, which provides the needed glyphs. jsPDF supports
> .ttf-files. So if you want to have for example chinese text in your
> pdf, your font has to have the necessary chinese glyphs. So check if
> your font supports the wanted glyphs or else it will show a blank
> space instead of the text.
>
> To add the font to jsPDF use our fontconverter in
> [/fontconverter/fontconverter.html](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html) . The fontconverter will create a
> js-file with the content of the provided ttf-file as base64 encoded
> string and additional code for jsPDF. You just have to add this
> generated js-File to your project. You are then ready to go to use
> setFont-method in your code and write your UTF-8 encoded text.

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/README.md#use-of-utf-8--ttf

Answer (score 1):

//use necessary config, read the docs http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html

```
import MuliSemiB64 from "../functions/MuliSemiB64";
let doc = new jsPDF({ 
    orientation: "p",
    unit: "px",
    format: "a5",
  });
doc.addFileToVFS("MULI-SEMIBOLD.TTF", MuliSemiB64());
```

//MuliSemiB64() is a function that returns the Muli ttf file in its base64 string format, convert your font ttf file and copy the string, save to a variable and use the function to return the string. Use a site like https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/ for the conversion

```
doc.addFont("MULI-SEMIBOLD.TTF", "Muli-Semi-Bold", "Semi-Bold");
doc.setFont("Muli-Semi-Bold", "Semi-Bold");
doc.text("Have Fun :*", 35, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I have found by far is using the [jspdf-customfonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-customfonts) package.
Simply install the package by
`npm i jspdf-customfonts`
then add the following files in the head tag of your index.html for default configurations

```
script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script> 
<script src="dist/jspdf.customfonts.min.js"></script> 
<script src="dist/default_vfs.js"></script>
```

Now you can download the ttf file of whichever font you want. Then go to [this](https://sphilee.github.io/jsPDF-CustomFonts-support/) site, select your font and copy the code, and you are done!

[image: jsPDF-CustomFonts]

Answer (score 0):

## Working Example

This is improvement of Dave Snydner [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981550/860099) by adding working example which support polish letters.

Example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/fy3nrg29/) (I not use SO snippets because it cause CORS errors...)

the main part is

```js
var callAddFont = function () {
  this.addFileToVFS('Lato-Regular-normal.ttf', font);
  this.addFont('Lato-Regular-normal.ttf', 'Lato-Regular', 'normal');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

Comment: well it seems that you do not have to add this method, as it is already merged into library. so you can just use Dave updated answer.