# Add Custom font in jspdf

Tags: javascript, fonts, jspdf

i want to use custom font such as 'Comic Sans MS' or 'Calibri' font in jsPDF.
i have found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908266/custom-font-faces-in-jspdf),  but mine is not working.
i already added the latest jspdf. and my code is like below :

```
        var doc = new jsPDF('p','mm','a4');

        doc.addFont('ComicSansMS', 'Comic Sans', 'normal','StandardEncoding');
        doc.setFont('Comic Sans');          
        doc.text(10, 10, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!");
        doc.output('dataurl');
```

but the pdf result's font is still the default font ( not comic sans ).
and there is no error. Please help...

Comment: You can try the detailed question and answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603013/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-jspdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have found the solution,

don't use the jspdf.js, but use the debug.jspdf.js

and after that add this code in the debug.jspdf.js

```
   API.addFont = function(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle) {
       addFont(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle, 'StandardEncoding');
   };
```

Answer (score 8):

I found this [github link](https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/)

[1](https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/): https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/js/basic.js#L390 and function name demoUsingTTFFont() useful for me.and to convert into base64 encoder [link](https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/)

Comment: This works after a few trial and error, i'm using JsPDF 1.5.3 with Vue.JS.

Comment: Worked for me also! 
Actually tried pretty much the same thing before and it didn´t work somehow, idk why. I used the MacOS Terminal base64 encoder... Maybe that thing was wrong, idk. This works tho! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since the other answers here are a little out of date, here is the solution I'm using...

First, as others have mentioned - you need these two libraries:

1. jsPDF: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
2. jsPDF-CustomFonts-support: https://github.com/sphilee/jsPDF-CustomFonts-support

Next - the second library *requires* that you provide it with at least one custom font in a file named `default_vfs.js`. I'm using *two* custom fonts - Arimo-Regular.ttf and Arimo-Bold.ttf - both from Google Fonts. So, my `default_vfs.js` file looks like this:

(

```
(function (jsPDFAPI) { 
    "use strict";
    jsPDFAPI.addFileToVFS('Arimo-Regular.ttf','[Base64-encoded string of your font]');
    jsPDFAPI.addFileToVFS('Arimo-Bold.ttf','[Base64-encoded string of your font]');
})(jsPDF.API);
```

Obviously, you version would look different, depending on the font(s) you're using.

There's a bunch of ways to get the Base64-encoded string for your font, but I used this: https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/.

It lets you upload a font .ttf file, and it'll give you the Base64 string that you can paste into `default_vfs.js`.

You can see what the actual file looks like, with my fonts, here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/stuehler/jsPDF-CustomFonts-support/master/dist/default_vfs.js

So, once your fonts are stored in that file, your HTML should look like this:

```
    <script src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jspdf.customfonts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/default_vfs.js"></script>
```

Finally, your JavaScript code looks something like this:

```
const doc = new jsPDF({
      unit: 'pt',
      orientation: 'p',
      lineHeight: 1.2
    });

doc.addFont("Arimo-Regular.ttf", "Arimo", "normal");
doc.addFont("Arimo-Bold.ttf", "Arimo", "bold");

doc.setFont("Arimo");
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.setFontSize(28);

doc.text("Hello, World!", 100, 100);

doc.setFontType("bold");

doc.text("Hello, BOLD World!", 100, 150);

doc.save("customFonts.pdf");
```

This is probably obvious to most, but in that `addFont()` method, the three parameters are:

1. The font's name you used in the `addFileToVFS()` function in the `default_vfs.js` file
2. The font's name you use in the `setFont()` function in your JavaScript
3. The font's style you use in the `setFontType()` function in your JavaScript

You can see this working here: https://codepen.io/stuehler/pen/pZMdKo

Hope this works as well for you as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question
looks like you missed this one out

```
 **************
    API.addFont = function(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle) {
          addFont(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle, 'StandardEncoding');
        };
    ****************
        doc.addFont('ComicSansMS', 'Comic Sans', 'normal');
        doc.setFont('Comic Sans');
        doc.text(50,50,'Hello World');

    http://stackoverflow.com/a/26981550/5086633
```

Comment: i already reference the link you mentioned in "here".  i have tried it but still not working.

Comment: in the latest jspdf.js from github,  it already contains those code. (API.addFont ....)