# Angular 6: How I use jspdf-customfonts

Tags: angular6, jspdf, custom-font

At first I infall jspdf. Its work very fine. Now I want to use UTF-8 fonts
I create a custom font like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961572/add-custom-font-in-jspdf)

For this I install:
npm i jspdf-customfonts
The I create default_vjs.js file:

```
(function (jsPDFAPI) { 
"use strict";
jsPDFAPI.addFileToVFS('PTSans-Regular.ttf', 'Base64-encoded string of my font');
jsPDFAPI.addFileToVFS('PTSans-Bold.ttf', 'Base64-encoded string of my font'); })(jsPDF.API);
```

and save it in the path: scr/app/js/default_vfs.js

I test it in my component:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

.......

```
const test = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
 test.addFont('PTSans-Regular.ttf', 'PTSans', 'normal');
 test.addFont('PTSans-Bold.ttf', 'PTSans', 'bold');
 test.setFont('PTSans');
 test.setFontType('normal');
 test.text(10, 10, 'Hallo Welt € ');
 test.save('customFont.pdf');
```

But its do not work. Die € sign is wrong. Can someone here tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem:
`regularNormal` is a Base64-encoded string of my font.

```
AddFontArimo(doc: jsPDF) {
   (doc as any).addFileToVFS('arimo.regular-normal.ttf', this.regularNormal);
}
```