# add custom font simsun in jsPDF

Tags: unicode, fonts, font-face, jspdf

I need export pdf with chinese letters, and write code as below link says:

[Custom font faces in jsPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908266/custom-font-faces-in-jspdf/26981550#26981550)

and my code:

css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SimSun;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("./simsun.ttc");
}

body{
  font-family: 'SimSun';
}
```

js:

```
pdf.addFont('SimSun', 'SimSun', 'normal','StandardEncoding');
pdf.setFont('SimSun');
pdf.text(20, 20, '西溪园区 5号楼 1F');
pdf.save('TestSVG.pdf');
```

And as someone said that, i have confirmed that addFont is public:

```
API.addFont = function(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle) {
    addFont(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle, 'StandardEncoding');
};
```

And i also find the postScriptName of 'Simsun' is SimSun.
http://mirror.sars.tw/FreeBSD_Chinese_HOWTO/simsun.html

Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load a truetype *collection*, not a truetype *font*. Current versions of CSS do not support font collections, so unpack your collection and then load the individual fonts, instead.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SimSun;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("./simsunregular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: SimSun;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("./simsunbold.ttf");
}

...etc...

body{
  font-family: 'SimSun';
}
```

Comment: this will affect words in html, but can not affect words in pdf. When i export pdf file and open with chrome, it's messy code.

Comment: then I'd recommend first asking in the first place you should ask: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues