# how to add and set a font in JsPDF?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I've been trying to set the Helvetica font in different ways but nothing seems to work. I understand the addFont and setFont function but I'm having problems using them.

This is what I have:

```
doc.addFont('Helvetica', 'Helvetica', 'normal')
doc.setFont('Helvetica')
```

Apparently the postscript name for Helvetica is 'Helvetica' so I don't know what it could be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981550/8637561

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom font faces in jsPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908266/custom-font-faces-in-jspdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[you can convert your font](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html)

Example PTSans-normal.js

`import jsPDF from 'jspdf'`
[jsPDF - Importing fonts in React.js / ES6 style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59950312/jspdf-importing-fonts-in-react-js-es6-style)

Using a new font

```
import 'assets/fonts/PTSans-normal.js';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

const doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFont('PTSans'); // set custom font
doc.setFontSize(12); // you can change size
doc.text('Hello', x, y) // and you can write your text

console.log('Show all font in jsPDF',doc.getFontList());
```

Answer (score 1):

No solution worked for me but the following...

**Step 1:** I Converted .ttf file to base64 .txt file. I used this link to achieve that https://www.base64encode.net/

**Step 2:** I added .txt file to vfs using addFileToVFS method

```
enter code here
doc.addFileToVFS('./fonts/verdana-normal.txt', 'verdana')
doc.addFileToVFS('./fonts/verdana-bold.txt', 'verdana')
doc.addFileToVFS('./fonts/verdanai.txt', 'verdana')
doc.addFileToVFS('./fonts/verdana-bold-italic.txt', 'verdana')
```

**Step 3:** Then I added to the font list

```
doc.addFont('./fonts/verdana-normal.ttf', 'Verdana', 'normal')
doc.addFont('./fonts/verdana-bold.ttf', 'Verdana', 'bold')
doc.addFont('./fonts/verdanai.ttf', 'Verdana', 'italic')
doc.addFont('./fonts/verdana-bold-italic.ttf', 'Verdana', 'italicbold')
```

You can check the font list if the is added:

```
console.log(doc.getFontList())
```

Please feel free to check out my github repo for this projects and more!!
[jsPdf cutom font](https://github.com/shahid-orion/jsPdf-custom-font)