# jsPDF - Importing fonts in React.js / ES6 style

Tags: reactjs, fonts, jspdf

I am trying to add a font in jsPDF in my React project. I converted the font to base64 and to a `.js` script using the provided generator at: https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html

I import the font script as:

```
import '../../assets/fonts/js/Muli-normal';
```

where `Muli-normal` is the converted `Muli-normal.js` file from `Muli.ttf` using the generator. I set the font with

```
doc.setFont('Muli')
```

but I get the error

```
  Line 10:5:  'jsPDF' is not defined  no-undef
```

The script is as follows:

```
// ../../assets/fonts/js/Muli-normal.js

(function (jsPDFAPI) {
var font = 'AAEAAAASAQAABAAgRkZUTW2ZUGwAAAE..
...
...
...ASAQAAB';
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Muli-normal.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Muli-normal.ttf', 'Muli', 'normal');
};
jsPDFAPI.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
})(jsPDF.API);
```

Comment: ...why would you need to turn it into base64 and then put that in a bundle?  It's a static asset, just directly link to it. See [Custom font faces in jsPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908266/custom-font-faces-in-jspdf) for how to do that, instead of making your bundle needlessly huge, with data that is static to begin with, and should not be in a bundle in the first place.

Comment: Because jsPDF requires base64 fonts? I looked for the documentation and Stackoverflow questions and most of them had the font first converted to .js and added to the bundle. I'd like to not add a mere copy of the .ttf files but thats the only working solution I found.

I tried the code in the link you provided but couldn't make it work. Do I add it like this? I guess the PR is already made so I don't have to modify the source code. The font is added with `@font-face`. This didn't work:
`doc.addFont('Muli', 'Muli', 'normal', 'StandardEncoding'); doc.setFont('Muli'); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the script does not recognize the jsPDF, one needs to import it using

```
﻿import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
```

so the script becomes:

```
// Muli-normal.js

﻿import jsPDF from 'jspdf'

(function (jsPDFAPI) {
var font = 'AAEAAAASAQAABAAgRkZUTW2ZUGwAAAE..
...
...
...ASAQAAB';
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Muli-normal.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Muli-normal.ttf', 'Muli', 'normal');
};
jsPDFAPI.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
})(jsPDF.API);
```

I still can't exactly figure out how the `Muli-normal.js` script is structured. (an IIFE module?). I figured to work it and answering my question but any explanations on this is welcome.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: I have already figured out this solution after 1 hour of frustration! then I stumbled upon your answer which is typical what I have did. So, yes you are totally correct and I have already open an issue about this particular bug at jsPDF github page.