# How to Use Custom Fonts with jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

Is it possible to include custom fonts in jsPDF ?

`addFont(postScriptName, fontName, fontStyle, 'StandardEncoding');`

I found this was possible by modifying jsPDF.js to expose the existing "addFont" method in the public API. Is there a way to do this?

Can someone please help?

Comment: It is possible - please check [how to add and set a font in JsPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885556/how-to-add-and-set-a-font-in-jspdf)